# Why am I getting the same value for the accuracy and recall when using spark's mllib's MulticlassClassificationEvaluator?

Tags: apache-spark

So, I am having a play around with some tree based algorithms from Spark's mllib. The code I have is here;

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import (RandomForestClassifier, GBTClassifier, DecisionTreeClassifier)
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.logConf', 'true').set("spark.ui.port", "4060")

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).appName("Gradient Boosted Tree").getOrCreate()

data = spark.read.parquet('/mydata/location)

def yt_func(x):
    if x <= 10:
        yt = 0
    else:
        yt = 1
    return yt

yt_udf = udf(yt_func, IntegerType())

data = data.withColumn('yt_1',yt_udf(data['count']))

datasub = data.select('feature1', 'feature2',
                      'feature3', 'feature4',
                      'feature5', 'feature6',
                      'feature7', 'feature8',
                      'feature9', 'feature10',
                      'feature11','feature12',
                      'feature13')

datasub = datasub.na.fill(0)

from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ['feature1', 'feature2',
                      'feature3', 'feature4',
                      'feature5', 'feature6',
                      'feature7', 'feature8',
                      'feature9', 'feature10',
                      'feature11','feature12',
                      'feature13'], outputCol = 'features')

output = assembler.transform(datasub)

finaldata = output.select('features','yt_1')

train_data,test_data = finaldata.randomSplit([0.7,0.3])

finaldata.show(20)

dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(featuresCol='features',labelCol='yt_1')
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(featuresCol='features',labelCol='yt_1', numTrees=70)
gbt = GBTClassifier(featuresCol='features',labelCol='yt_1')

dtc_model = dtc.fit(train_data)
rfc_model = rfc.fit(train_data)
gbt_model = gbt.fit(train_data)

dtc_preds = dtc_model.transform(test_data)
rfc_preds = rfc_model.transform(test_data)
gbt_preds = gbt_model.transform(test_data)

dtc_preds.show()
rfc_preds.show()
gbt_preds.show()

accuracy_eval = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName = 'accuracy', labelCol='yt_1')
recall_eval = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName = 'weightedRecall', labelCol='yt_1')

print 'dtc accuracy:', accuracy_eval.evaluate(dtc_preds)
print 'dtc recall', recall_eval.evaluate(dtc_preds)

print 'rfc accuracy:', accuracy_eval.evaluate(rfc_preds)
print 'rfc recall', recall_eval.evaluate(rfc_preds)

print 'gbt accuracy:', accuracy_eval.evaluate(gbt_preds)
print 'gbt recall', recall_eval.evaluate(gbt_preds)
```

When I run this I get the following;

```
dtc accuracy: 0.98596755767033761
dtc recall: 0.98596755767033761

rfc accuracy: 0.98551077243825225
rfc recall: 0.98551077243825225

gbt accuracy: 0.98624595624862965
gbt recall: 0.98624595624862965
```

What is confusing me here is why I am getting the same values for the accuracy and the recall.... they are EXACTLY the same. Surely this isn't correct....??

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct. You can see comments to this effect in the docs/source. In a multiclass setting, overall precision and recall are the same.

Precision and recall in the "binary" classification case is really reporting precision with respect to one of the two classes: the positive one. There are in fact two classes, but we tend to think of it as class vs not-class.

However in multiclass, there is no positive and negative. All N classes are equal, and precision and recall are computed over all N classes, not N-1. This ends up making their definition the same.

To see it, consider the confusion matrix of a multiclass classifier, with predicted class down the rows and actual classes across the columns. "True positives" are equivalent to all the diagonal entries: these are the cases where predicated and actual classes match. "False positives" occur when the predicted class is wrong: these are all the entries in each row that aren't on the diagonal. "False negatives" occur when the actual class isn't the predicted one: these are all the entries in each column that aren't on the diagonal.

But the sum of rows (less the diagonal) is the same as the sum of columns (less the diagonal). So the false positive and false negative count are the same. And from the definition of precision and recall, this makes their values the same.

In fact, both equal the accuracy of the multiclass classifier.

Comment: Great answer, however in my case, I am using the MulticlassClassificationEvaluator to test a binary case. Should in this situation we not expect them to be different?

Comment: I suppose the MulticlassClassificationEvaluator is not appropriate for testing a Binary case due to what you mentioned in your second paragraph :)